# how do I pass many php variables to python

Tags: php, arrays, variables, python-2.7, exec

I am using the following code to initiate a python script and pass a php variable to it.

```
$tmp = exec("python path/to/pythonfile.py $myVariable $mySecondVariable", $output);
```

This works very well, my issue is that I will need to pass 100+ variables to the python script. I don't want this exec line to become extremely long and unmanageable. I have also explored passing a php array instead of a variable with the following code:

```
$checked = array(
"key1"     => "1"
"key2"     => "1"
"key3"     => "1"
);
$checkedJson = json_encode($checked);
$tmp = exec("python path/to/pythonfile.py $myVariable $checkedJson", $output);
```

With this I have been unable to decode the JSON on the python side. I have been able to do a basic print of the array variable(undecoded) in python, but it gives every individual character as a new array value. ie [0] = k, [1] = e, [2] = y, [3] = 1, etc...
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Just to be clear,I am looking for a simpler method than encoding and decoding an array. Is there a way I can format the exec line to allow for multiple variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your PHP variables within a temporary text file then use python to read that file.

Simple and effective.

---

*Assuming Scripts are in the same directory*

**PHP Portion**

*long version (self contained script - skip to the short version below if you only want the code snippet)*

```
<?php

#Establish an array with all parameters you'd like to pass. 
#Either fill it manually or with a loop, ie:

#Loop below creates 100 dummy variables with this pattern.  
#You'd need to come up with a way yourself to fill a single array to pass
#$variable1 = '1';
#$variable2 = '2';
#$variable3 = '3';
#....
#$variableN = 'N';
#...    
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    ${'variable'.$i} = $i;
}

#Create/Open a file and prepare it for writing
$tempFile = "temp.dat";
$fh = fopen($tempFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

#let's say N=100
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {

    #for custom keys 
    $keyname = 'Key'.$i;

    # using a variable variable here to grab $variable1 ... $variable2 ... $variableN     ... $variable100
    $phpVariablesToPass[$keyname] = ${'variable'.$i} + 1000;

}

#phpVariablesToPass looks like this:
# [Key1] => 1001 [Key2] => 1002 [Key3] => 1003  [KeyN] = > (1000+N)


#now write to the file for each value.  
#You could modify the fwrite string to whatever you'd like
foreach ($phpVariablesToPass as $key=>$value) {
    fwrite($fh, $value."\n");
}


#close the file
fclose($fh);

?>
```

*or in short, assuming $phpVariablesToPass is an array filled with your values:*

```
#Create/Open a file and prepare it for writing
$tempFile = "temp.dat";
$fh = fopen($tempFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
foreach ($phpVariablesToPass as $key=>$value) {
    fwrite($fh, $value."\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

**Python Snippet to Grab the Data**

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('temp.dat')]
```

the variable *lines* now contains all of your php data as a python list.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like an example on how to do this.  I've moved countless large datasets between languages/scripts using temp files, and it really is the way to go.

Comment: Sure that would be helpful.

Comment: Hope those examples help.  Make sure that temp.dat permissions are set so that php can open/write to the file and python can open/read the file.   Mainly focus on the short version of the php for the snippet.  The long version is a self contained script that you can use as a template.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this is a bit of a side project at the moment.