# passing php variable to python file

Tags: php, python, shell-exec, sys

i have a php file which have some variables para1 and para2 , i want to send them to a python file .
this is my php file:

```
<?php

$para1 = "one";
$para2 = "two";
echo "shell_exec("
/C:/xampp/htdocs/Ai_Edutech_trial_project/eclipse_workspace/Project
/check.py '$para1' '$para2'")";
?>
```

and this is my py file:

```
import sys

x=sys.argv[1]
y=sys.argv[2]

print(x)
print(y)
```

but this does not work for me. Can someone please help me with this or suggest some other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721066/execute-python-in-a-php-script-using-shell-exec)

Comment: Why do you have quotes around `shell_exec(`? That prevents calling the function.

Comment: ohh yes .. well i have tried that but it shows no output. is there any path argument error in function or anything else...? or should i use something other than print() in py...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute python in a php script using shell\_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721066/execute-python-in-a-php-script-using-shell-exec)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I pass many php variables to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451272/how-do-i-pass-many-php-variables-to-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable from PHP to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197815/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put quotes around the function call. That turns it into a literal string, not a call to the function. Windows pathnames don't use a `/` before the drive letter, so the path should start with `C:`. And there shouldn't be a space after `Project`.

```
echo shell_exec("C:/xampp/htdocs/Ai_Edutech_trial_project/eclipse_workspace/Project/check.py '$para1' '$para2'");
```

Also, if you're just going to echo the result, you can use the `passthru` function instead.

Comment: ohh yes .. well i have tried that but it shows no output. is there any path argument error in function or anything else...? or should i use something other than print() in py...?

Comment: Get rid of `/` before `C:`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Solved it by adding the word python in front of the path to the python script.
As in:

```
echo shell_exec("python C:/xampp/htdocs/Ai_Edutech_trial_project/eclipse_workspace/Project/check.py '$para1' '$para2'");
```