# how do I get .php file variable to .py file

Tags: python, php, xampp, localhost, localserver

.php file code

```
<?php
$para1 = "one";
echo shell_exec("python C:/xampp/htdocs/python/test.py '$para1'");
?>
```

.py file code

```
#! C:\Users\mhammad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\r\n") #this code is for run .py file in xampp localserver.
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

output of python file while running on xampp server in browser.
`['C:/xampp/htdocs/python/test.py']`

how do I get variable value from .php file to .py file.

Comment: This the real code? Because single quotes around `one` don't seem very useful. (And CMD usually expects double quotes or carets for escaping.)

Comment: Yes this is the real code   link prefer:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015210/passing-php-variable-to-python-file 
 and if I remove single quotes from $para1 it print same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This above mentioned code is working absolutely fine but the twist is that the xyz.py file is running in background on command line terminal and this  `print(sys.argv)` can use the variable value `$para1 = "one";` in xyz.py file and print the value of that shared variable.
thanks